# Magento 2 Set Shipping Method Programatically

Tags: magento2.3, shipping-methods, programmatically

I am trying to set Shipping Method Progrmatically but getting following error.
**The shipping method is missing. Select the shipping method and try again.**

```
foreach ($quote->getAllAddresses() as $address) {
            // Build grand total.
        $grandTotal = (($finalPrice + $shipping + $tax) - $discount);
        $baseGrandTotal =  $this->convertPrice($grandTotal);
        $baseFinalPrice =  $this->convertPrice($finalPrice);
        $baseDiscount =  $this->convertPrice($discount);
        $baseTax =  $this->convertPrice($tax);

        //$address->setFreeShipping(true); //tried this but not getting set

        $address->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate'); //tried this getting error
        $address->setCollectShippingRates(true);


        $address->setBaseSubtotal($baseFinalPrice);
        $address->setSubtotal($finalPrice);
        $address->setDiscountAmount($discount);
        $address->setBaseDiscountAmount($baseDiscount);
        $address->setTaxAmount($tax);
        $address->setBaseTaxAmount($baseTax);
        $address->setBaseGrandTotal($baseGrandTotal);
        $address->setGrandTotal($grandTotal);
        $address->save();

}
```

Comment: First, you have to calculate the total then you have to check the available shipping method and then apply Shipping method.

Answer (score 1):

Use the out-of-the-box Magento 2 code to set/reset the Shipping method, which resets the old Delivery method in the cart to the new one.

```
use Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Checkout\Api\ShippingInformationManagementInterface;
```

======

```
public function __construct(
        ShippingInformationInterfaceFactory $shippingInformationFactory,
        ShippingInformationManagementInterface $shippingInformationManagement
    ) {

        $this->shippingInformationFactory = $shippingInformationFactory;
        $this->shippingInformationManagement = $shippingInformationManagement;
    }


   $shippingInformation = $this->shippingInformationFactory->create([
                'data' => [
                    /* If the address is not a shipping address (but billing) the system will find the proper shipping
                       address for the selected cart and set the information there (actual for single shipping address) */
                    ShippingInformationInterface::SHIPPING_ADDRESS => $shippingAddress,
                    ShippingInformationInterface::SHIPPING_CARRIER_CODE => self::FREESHIPPING,
                    ShippingInformationInterface::SHIPPING_METHOD_CODE => self::FREESHIPPING,
                ],
            ]);
            $this->shippingInformationManagement->saveAddressInformation($cart->getId(), $shippingInformation);
```

Then save data

Comment: thanks a lot....

Answer (score 0):

Please update the code like below

```
$address->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate'); 
$address->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates();
```

Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Still same error

Comment: @ramkrishan if i try to use setshippingmethod and then if i use getshippingmethod the result is empty

Answer (score 0):

**Please update this code :-**

```
 $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();

 $shippingAddress->setFreeShipping(true);
 $shippingAddress->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');
 $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true);
```